# When you are enter the text how to increase the textview hight automatically based on text in iOS Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I'm working on UITextView, when I enter the text in TextView then it should automatically increases the hight of TextView.

**For Example:** `textView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 10, 100, 10);`

In my scenario, I enter the text continuously it will automatically increase the hight of textview?

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the textViewDidChange delegate method on UITextView:

First, make sure your viewController conforms to the delegate protocol

```
// In viewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

Then something like this should get you started:

```
// In viewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    float initialTextViewHeight;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the initialHeight of your textView
    initialTextViewHeight = 100.0;

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, initialTextViewHeight)];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [textView setDelegate:self];
    [textView setScrollEnabled:FALSE];
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{

    // Figure out the frame size of the text in the textView so we know how much to grow the textView's height by.
    CGRect frame = [textView.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width - 10.0, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                            attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:textView.font }
                                               context:nil];

    // Take the height of the text from the frame
    float textHeight = frame.size.height + 10.0;

    // If you start with a large textView height initally it will shrink when typing begins because
    // the text height is intially small.  To prevent this, we add the conditional below.  If the textHeight
    // is greater than the initial height, we know the textHeight has now outgrown the size of the textView and it's time
    // to increase the textView's height.
    if (textHeight > initialTextViewHeight)
      [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(textView.frame.origin.x, textView.frame.origin.y, textView.frame.size.width, textHeight)];

}
```

Comment: Why do you have `+10.0`?

Comment: I think `float textHeight = frame.size.height+textView.textContainerInset.top+textView.textContainerInset.bottom;` is a safer alternative than using magic numbers. This code works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position {
    CGRect originalRect = [super caretRectForPosition:position];
    originalRect.size.height = 18.;
    return originalRect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, in your case if you are adding more and more lines then instead of increasing the uitextview's height it actually enables the scrolling feature and will give you the access to scroll down to your recently entered text.

**Now the solution to your Question** -

First of all you need to calculate the current size of uitextview after updating the text.

Next you have to update the frame of the uitextview with your own modified value.

You can get the current content size by the UITextView's contentsize property.

Here is some code snippet

```
 CGRect oldFrame = _textViewToEdit.frame;

 oldFrame.size.height = _textViewToEdit.contentSize.height;
 _textViewToEdit.frame = oldFrame;
```

You can put the above last two lines inside a function and fire that inside your UITextView's delegate method called -

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
```

Thanks

Hope This Helped.

Comment: Thanks, But  self._textViewToEdit.frame = frame;
What is the frame?

Comment: Check out the variable name. It just the old frame of textview before edit. After getting the new value you need to update the height and update the frame of your textview as well.

Now its updated...check that...sorry for the inconvenience mate.

Answer (score 0):

[CSGrowingTextView](https://github.com/cloverstudio/CSGrowingTextView) is also a UITextView which grows depending on text which may help you. Feel free to examine code, it may help you in the end.